# How to synchronize python and c sharp program running in windows?

Tags: python, c#, synchronization, data-synchronization

I am currently working in a project where I need to sychronise data between python and c sharp.I need to label data from c sharp using python machine learning program. To label the data, I am using timestamp from both the application and based on the common timestamp, I am labelling the data.

Python program is running every 0.5 to 1.5 sec and C sharp program is running 10 times every 1 sec. Since the two process are running differently, I know there is some time lag. So labelling the data using the timestamp is not much accurate. I want to analyse the time lag properly. For this I am looking for options of real time synchronization between the two programs. I have looked into sockets but I think there is a better way using IPC. I donot know much about this.

I am thinking to create a shared variable between python and c#. Since python is slower, I will update that variable using python and read that variable from c# program. so same variable instance on both the program would tell us that they are synchronized perfectly. So I can look the value of this variable instead of timestamp for labelling the data. I am thinking that this might solve the issue. Please let me know what would be the best optimal solution to minimize the time difference lag between the two program.

since these are complex projects, I cannot implement them in a single program. I need to find a way to synchronize these two programs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried working with socket programming but they were not that good and a bit complex. So I am now thinking about IPC but still not sure which is the best way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I implemented a socket in C# program so that I get data from the socket. Then I implemented multiprocessing in python. One process will request to the socket and another process will work for ML model. I was able to achieve the synchronization using the multiprocessing module. I used multiprocessing.Event() to wait for the event from another process. You can also look into shared variables in python using multiprocessing.Value, multiprocessing.Array, multiprocessing.Event.